# List of multiple dataframes to separate Excel sheets

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have a list of dataframes of variable length, and I want to convert each list of dataframes to each excel sheet.

Here is my code:

```
for i in range(1, len(dfs)):
    frames = {'sheetName_i' : dfs[i]}
for sheet, df in frames.items():
    dfs[i].to_excel(writer, index=False)
#df is the whole dataframe whereas dfs is the list of df
```

I got only the last list at my output.
Is there any way I can convert all the lists to separatel Excel sheets?

I have used your suggestion as below:

```
for i, df in enumerate(dfs, 1):
   for n in group: #containe the names that I want to name the sheets amd the names equal to the number of sheets.
       df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=n.format(i))
```

Sheetnames are changed to the names, which I need. Whereas the data of every sheet is similar, some content of data is missed and some data is merged in the single sheet and same data is repeated in every sheet. 
Is there any way I can get the correct output.

Pleased to hear some suggestions. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
for i, df in enumerate(dfs, 1):
    #python 3.6+
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False,sheet_name=f'sheetName_{i}')
    #below python 3.6   
    #df.to_excel(writer, index=False,sheet_name='sheetName_{}'.format(i))
writer.save()
```

---

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

#sample list of DataFrames
dfs = [df[['A','B']], df[['A','B','C']],df[['A','F']]]

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
for i, df in enumerate(dfs, 1):
    #python 3.6+
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False,sheet_name=f'sheetName_{i}')
    #below python 3.6   
    #df.to_excel(writer, index=False,sheet_name='sheetName_{}'.format(i))
writer.save()
```

EDIT:

If need write custom names of sheetnames:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
names = ['a','d','b']
for df, n in zip(dfs, names):
    #python 3.6+
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False,sheet_name=f'sheetName_{n}')
    #below python 3.6   
    #df.to_excel(writer, index=False,sheet_name='sheetName_{}'.format(n))
writer.save()
```

Comment: I got the syntax error at the sheet name, can you please explain me what is f at the sheet name

Comment: @Vishali - Solution is form python 3.6+, added also solution for below versions, please check it.

Comment: Thank you very much I got want i need

Comment: Is it possible to change the sheetnames to the column F values in your above sample, say they have unique values in a sheet similarly with other sheets as well, and have that column in every sheet.

Comment: @Vishali - I think best is create dictioanry like `d = {'a':df1, 'b':df2}` and then loop by it with `for i, df in d.items():` and `df.to_excel(writer, index=False,sheet_name=f'sheetName_{i}')`

Comment: @jezrael- Is it possible to create dictionary by using column name without using the column values as the column name is similar to every sheet.

Comment: @Vishali - Not sure if understand, what should be new sheetnames ?

Comment: @jezrael- Is there any way I consider only if the columns has values otherwise not. Because, I get few blank sheets with just the column names. Can you please suggest me.

Comment: So there is emty DataFrame? Do you need remove emty DataFrames from list?

Comment: @jezrael- yes, exactly.

Comment: @Vishali - use `dfs = [x for x in dfs if not x.empty]`

Comment: @Vishali - sample `dfs = [pd.DataFrame(), pd.DataFrame({'a':[21, 10,20]}), pd.DataFrame()]
dfs = [x for x in dfs if not x.empty]`

Comment: @jezrael- Thanks a lot

Comment: @jezrael- I tried to rename the sheets by collecting the column values in a list, and then using the for loop I have assigned to sheetname as follow: for n in group: df2.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=n.format(i)). But, the dataframes did not split based on the list, whereas I got the different ouput. Is there anyway I can do correctly? Can you please suggest me if you can.

Comment: `group` is list of DataFrames?

Comment: No, list of column values, that I want to rename the sheetnames to

Comment: @ali - not sure if understand, if want set new names is not possible use `sheet_name=n` ?

Comment: Instead of sheetNames I have given n since I want the sheetnames to change, I want to know if I can use n in the same for loop instead of using another for loop.

Comment: @ali - I think your solution is good, need another loop, because for dataframe need multiple sheetnames, so `df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name=n)` should working.

Comment: @jezrael- I used your suggestion, but got the same incorrect result.

Comment: @jezrael-Thanks a lot:)