# change the sheetname to the duplicated column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple sheets, each sheet having similar columns. I want to change the sheet name to the one of the duplicated column values.

For example:

```
A  B   C  D
1  X1  5  ftr
2  X1  3  nbg
3  X1  2  nhg
4  X1  3  ght
5  X1  2  fgt
```

I have converted the multiple dataframes to excel using the below answer:
[List of multiple dataframes to separate Excel sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52849830/list-of-multiple-dataframes-to-separate-excel-sheets).
I want to replace sheet name to the 'B' column value (X1).
I want to remove the sheets if 'B' column values are empty.
I would like to know is there any possibilities.
Pleased to hear some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Find the duplicate column and store its value by below code:

```
df1= pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,1,1,1,1],
                  'C': np.random.randn(5)})

nunique = df1.apply(pd.Series.nunique)
value_col = nunique[nunique == 1] ## Value_col will have "1". In your case it will be "X1"
```

Now Import openpyxl to rename the sheet

```
import openpyxl
file_name=openpyxl.load_workbook("sample.xlsx")
sheet_name = file_name.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet')
if len(value_col) == 1:
    sheet_name.title = value_col[0]

else:
    file_name.remove_sheet(sheet_name)

ss.save("sample.xlsx")
```

Comment: I have an empty sheets which I would like to remove it by checking the value_col, if the value is empty. Can you please suggest me.

Comment: You mean if the value of `value_col` comes null or whatever meaning there is no column with duplicate values. You need to delete that sheet. Correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly. As I mentioned in my question I use the 'sheetName_{}'.format(i) where i is the number of sheets. Now, I want to remove the sheets with no column.

Comment: No duplicated column and when the column values are empty too

Comment: Yes, if the columns don't have value, I want to remove the sheets

Comment: Names are in the sheet, whereas the value of columns are empty.

Comment: Updated the answer...just manage your sheet_name logic...rest all will work

Comment: Is it possible to give the column name instead of '1' in your answer. Since, the values differs with sheets. In addition, I have other columns too having the duplicates. Can you please suggest me since I have around 20 sheets and I cannot write the values.

Comment: Replace `value_col[0]` with `value_col.index[0]`

Comment: Unfortunately, get_sheet_by_name only work for single sheet but not for multiple sheets. Can you suggest me for the multiple sheets.

Comment: `get_sheet_by_name` gives you the name of particular sheet, if you want to get all the sheet names it will be `file_name.get_sheet_names()` or `file_name.sheetnames`

Comment: I have used, sheets = file_name.sheetnames. Using the for loop i tried assigning the values to sheet.title for sheet in sheets. But, I got error as 'str' object attribute 'title' is read-only. Can you please suggest me

Comment: If I use the sheets = file_name.sheetnames, sheets.title = value_col[0]. I get the AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'title'.